# Groups in which $[a, b][b^{-1}, a^{-1}] = 1$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, I'm in a situation where this holds for all $a,b \in G$: $[a, b][b^{-1}, a^{-1}] = 1$, I believe this implies that $[a, b] = 1$ for all $a$, $b$, however, I cannot seem to prove this. Is this assertion correct? If so why?

Comment: See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: Does $[a,b]$ mean the commutator $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ ? If not what is it?

Comment: @user2661923 Your comment only directs the OP to a general page of "how to ask a question" advice. In my opinion it's wording "see this" makes it look like you refer to an answer on stack to OP's question, a bit misleading.

Comment: Please use Mathjax to format your questions.

Comment: @coffeemath I am intentionally being misleading.  In my opinion, about 95% of the queries posted have serious defects.  No one has come up with a better approach to improve the quality of the queries posted.  If you have an alternative way of improving the quality of the queries, other than directing the OP to an article that clarifies the query's defects, I would like to know about it.

Comment: @user2661923 I think Arturo's comment is not misleading. Yours makes other users (I was one) think the link goes to an answer or relevant post.

Comment: @coffeemath It is an unfortunate side effect that misleading the OP also means misleading other reviewers.  Weigh that against [1] The value of tricking the OP into confronting an article that highlights the query's defects [2] Tricking reviewers accomplishes nothing but only results in a few seconds of inconvenience.

Comment: @Avi: You have been in the site for over a year. Shouldn’t you know by now to format your questions properly? It really shows utter disregard to the people you are asking to help you.

Comment: @user2661923 I'm not a fan of this "tricking new users" policy, as it seems at odds with our [Code of Conduct](https://math.stackexchange.com/conduct). We are supposed to "Be inclusive and respectful", and assuming that a new user needs to be mislead in order to receive constructive criticism strikes me as disrespectful.

Comment: @user2661923 I agree with Theo's comment above, and find your "see this" trick not worth it because of misleading readers other than the OP.

Comment: @coffemath Okay, you and Theo Bendit both make excellent points.  I will eliminate deceit from my strategy.

Comment: @TheoBendit See my previous comment.

Comment: @TheoBendit "and assuming that a new user needs to be mislead in order to receive constructive criticism strikes me as disrespectful." As I say, I am going to abandon the deceit because it seems to have caused controversy.  However, as a factual matter, while assuming that a new user needs to be mislead may be disrespectful, it also seems to be an accurate assumption, based on the prevailing evidence.

Comment: The groups that satisfy your condition are precisely the $2$-Engel groups (which are also groups in which any $2$-generated subgroup is nilpotent of class at most $2$). I've added a proof.

Answer (score 6):

This is not true. In any group, $[x,y]^{-1}=[y,x]$. And in any nilpotent group of class at most $2$, the commutator bracket is bilinear, so $[x^a,y^b]=[x,y]^{ab}$ for all $x$ and $y$ and all integers $a$ and $b$. Therefore, if $G$ is nilpotent of class at most $2$, then $[a,b][b^{-1},a^{-1}]=[a,b][b,a]=1$ for all $a,b$, but if $G$ is not abelian, then you do not get $[a,b]=1$ for all $a$ and $b$.

(The above holds regardless of whether your convention is that $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ or that $[x,y]=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$).

For a specific example, take the Dihedral group of order $8$,
$$D_8 = \langle r,s\mid r^4=s^2=1, sr=r^3s\rangle.$$
For any two elements $a,b$ of $D_8$, if they commute then $[a,b]=1$, and if $a$ and $b$ do not commute then $[a,b]=r^2$. Therefore, $[a,b][b^{-1},a^{-1}]=1$ in all cases (since $a$ and $b$ commute if and only if $b^{-1}$ and $a^{-1}$ commute). But $D_8$ is not abelian.

---

To characterize these groups: if $[a,b][b^{-1},a^{-1}]=1$, then $[a,b]=[b^{-1},a^{-1}]^{-1} = [a^{-1},b^{-1}]$.  Thus, the given condition is equivalent to

> $$[x,y]=[x^{-1},y^{-1}]\quad\text{for all }x,y\in G.$$

Your groups are precisely the $2$-Engel groups. Here's a proof.

I will use the convention that $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$, and the following identities, which can be verified by direct calculation:
$$[xz,y] = [x,y]^z[z,y]\quad\text{and}\quad [x,zy]=[x,y][x,z]^y$$

Recall that a group $G$ is said to be $n$-Bell if $[x^n,y]=[x,y^n]$ for all $x,y\in G$, and $n$-Levi if $[x^n,y]=[x,y]^n$ for all $x,y\in G$.

**Proposition.** A group $G$ satisfies $[a,b]=[a^{-1},b^{-1}]$ for all $a,b\in G$ if and only if $G$ is $(-1)$-Bell.

*Proof.* If $G$ is $(-1)$-Bell, then $[a^{-1},b^{-1}] = [a,(b^{-1})^{-1}] = [a,b]$. Conversely, if $G$ satisfies the identity, then
$$[x^{-1},y] = [x^{-1},(y^{-1})^{-1}] = [x,y^{-1}],$$
proving that $G$ is $(-1)$-Bell. $\Box$

The following can be deduced from the description of the Bell semigroup of a group given in

- Kappe , L.C. *[On n-Levi groups](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01191994).* Arch. Math. (Basel) 47 (1986), no. 3, 198–210. [MR0861866](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=861866) (88a:20048)

but here is a direct argument.

**Lemma.** If $G$ is $n$-Bell (that is, $[x^n,y]=[x,y^n]$ for all $x,y\in G$) then it is also $(1-n)$-Bell (that is, $[x^{1-n},y]=[x,y^{1-n}]$ for all $x,y\in G$). If $G$ is both $n$-Bell and $m$-Bell, then it is also $nm$-Bell.

*Proof.* Suppose that $[x^n,y]=[x,y^n]$. Expanding we have
$$x^{-n}y^{-1}x^ny = x^{-1}y^{-n}xy^n.$$
Left multiplying by $yx$ and right multiplying by $y^{-1}x^{-1}$ we get
$$yx^{1-n}y^{-1}x^{n-1} = y^{1-n}xy^{n-1}x^{-1}$$
or equivalently, that $[y^{-1},x^{n-1}] = [y^{n-1},x^{-1}]$. Setting $a=y^{-1}$, $b=x^{-1}$, we get that
$$[a,b^{1-n}] = [a^{1-n},b]$$
holds for all $a,b\in G$.

If $G$ is both $n$-Bell and $m$-Bell, then
$$[x^{nm},y] = [(x^m)^n,y] = [x^m,y^n] = [x,(y^n)^m] = [x,y^{nm}]$$
for all $x,y\in G$, so $G$ is also $nm$-Bell, as claimed. $\Box$

Note that this means that a group is $2$-Bell if and only if it is $-1$-Bell, since $-1 = 1-2$ and $2=1-(-1)$.

**Proposition.** Let $G$ be a group. Then $[x^{-1},y]=[x,y^{-1}]$ for all $x,y\in G$, if and only if $G$ is $n$-Bell for all integers $n$.

*Proof.* It is clear that if $G$ is $n$-Bell for all $n$, then the result holds (take $n=-1$). Conversely, if $G$ is $-1$-Bell, then by the Lemma it is also $2$-Bell, since $1-(-1)=2$. If $G$ is $k$-Bell, then it is also $-k$-Bell (since it is both $k$-Bell and $-1$-Bell), and therefore it is also $(k+1)$-Bell (since $1-(-k) = 1+k$). This proves $G$ is $n$-Bell for all positive $n$; and therefore, since it is also $-1$-Bell, it is $n$-Bell for all integers $n$, as claimed. (Note that every group is $0$-Bell and $1$-Bell). $\Box$.

**Corollary.** Let $G$ be a group. The following are equivalent:

1. $G$ satisfies $[x,y]=[x^{-1},y^{-1}]$ for all $x,y\in G$.
2. $G$ is $-1$-Bell.
3. $G$ is $2$-Bell.
4. $G$ is $n$-Bell for every integer $n$.

*Proof.* The equivalence of 2, 3, and 4 is given above. If $G$ is $n$-Bell for all integers $n$, then $[x^{-1},y^{-1}] = [x,(y^{-1})^{-1}] = [x,y]$. Conversely, if $[x,y]=[x^{-1},y^{-1}]$ for all $x,y\in G$, then
$$[x^{-1},y] = [x^{-1},(y^{-1})^{-1}] = [x,y^{-1}]$$
so $G$ is $-1$-Bell, and therefore by the Proposition above it is $n$-Bell for all $n$. $\Box$

Recall that a group $G$ is $2$-Engel if $[y,x,x]=1$ for all $x$ and $y$ (here, $[a,b,c] = [[a,b],c]$). This is equivalent to $[x,y,x]=1$ for all $x,y\in G$, since $x$ commutes with $[y,x]$ if and only if it commutes with $[x,y]=[y,x]^{-1}$. A group is $2$-Engel if and only if every $2$-generated subgroup is nilpotent of class at most $2$. We have:

**Proposition.** Let $G$ be a group. The following are equivalent:

1. $G$ is $2$-Engel.
2. $G$ is $2$-Levi.
3. $G$ is $2$-Bell.

*Proof.* If $G$ is $2$-Engel, then
$$\begin{align*}
[x^2,y] &= [xx,y] = [x,y]^x[x,y]\\
&= x^{-1}[x,y]x[x,y]\\
&= [x,y][x,y]^{-1}x^{-1}[x,y]x[x,y]\\
&= [x,y][[x,y],x][x,y]\\
&= [x,y][x,y,x][x,y]\\
&= [x,y]^2,
\end{align*}$$
so $G$ is $2$-Levi.

If $G$ is $2$-Levi, then it is also $2$-Bell: if $[x^2,y]=[x,y]^2$ for all $x,y\in G$, then
$$[x,y^2] = ([y^2,x])^{-1} = ([y,x]^2)^{-1} = ([y,x]^{-1})^2 = [x,y]^2,$$ so $[x^2,y]=[x,y]^2=[x,y^2]$.

Finally, if $G$ is $2$-Bell, it is $n$-Bell for all $n$, hence $-1$-Bell. We have
$$1 = [1,y] = [x^{-1}x,y] = [x^{-1},y]^x[x,y] = [x,y^{-1}]^x[x,y]$$
and
$$1 = [x,1] = [x,y^{-1}y] = [x,y][x,y^{-1}]^y = [x,y][x^{-1},y]^y.$$
Thus, $[x,y^{-1}]^x[x,y] = [x,y][x^{-1},y]^y$, so
$$([x,y^{-1}]^x)^{[x,y]} = [x,y]^{-1}[x,y^{-1}]^x[x,y] = [x^{-1},y]^y,$$
which gives, using the $-1$-Bell property
$$[x^{-1},y]^{x[x,y]} = [x^{-1},y]^y.$$
Therefore, $[x^{-1},y]$ commutes with $x[x,y]y^{-1} = x(x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)y^{-1} = y^{-1}x$. Thus,
$$[x^{-1},y,y^{-1}x]=1$$
holds for all $x,y$. In particular, substituting $yx$ for $x$,
$$\begin{align*}
1&=[(yx)^{-1},y,y^{-1}(yx)]\\ 
&= [(yx)^{-1},y,x] 
&= [yx,y^{-1},x]\\
&= \Bigl[[yx,y^{-1}],x\Bigr]\\
&= \Bigl[ [y,y^{-1}]^x[x,y^{-1}],x\Bigr]\\
&= [x,y^{-1},x].
\end{align*}$$
Thus, for all $x,y\in G$, $[x,y^{-1},x]=1$. Therefore, $[x,y,x]=1$ holds, and thus $[y,x,x]=1$ holds for all $x,y\in G$, proving that $G$ is $2$-Engel. $\Box$

Thus we conclude:

> **Theorem.**  A group $G$ satisfies the identity $[a,b][b^{-1},a^{-1}]=1$  for all $a,b\in G$ if and only if $G$ is $2$-Engel.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I was really taking myself for a ride on this one and the answer ended up being more elegant than I thought it was. I'm glad to know that I was wrong about my conjecture though since it was driving me a bit crazy. Very helpful!

Comment: @AviTachna-Fram: Now please take the time to fix your post and use Mathjax.